# Restrict number of WebParts added on a page - For specific users

Tags: sharepoint

i have a SharePoint site with two groups "Creators" "Admins" .

When we edit a sharepoint page and goto "Insert" tab, we will see the following options
1. Insert webpart,
2. upload files

I want to restrict the "Creators" to upload file and they can insert maximum 2 webparts. Admins has no restrictions.

Is it possible with SP2010?

Answer (score 1):

One approach, you should be able to connect an event to the Insert Webpart button. If it isn't included in SharePoint use your own javascript or some thing like that.

Another approach, you can count the number of available webparts on page load. If someone added more than the max allowed simply remove the newest one.

You can count them with something like this

```
ClientContext oClientContext = new ClientContext("http://server/site");
File oFile = oClientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl("Default.aspx");
LimitedWebPartManager limitedWebPartManager = oFile.GetLimitedWebPartManager(PersonalizationScope.Shared);

oClientContext.Load(limitedWebPartManager.WebParts,
    wps => wps.Include(
    wp => wp.WebPart.Title));

oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (limitedWebPartManager.WebParts.Count >= 2)
{
    // Max amount of webparts...
}
```

To delete

```
WebPartDefinition webPartDefinition = limitedWebPartManager.WebParts[2]; // Third web part
webPartDefinition.DeleteWebPart();
oClientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: Since there is no direct solution in SharePoint, this is very useful and i will proceed with this. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, if this shows to be the solution please remember to close the question by marking this or another post as the answer.